# How can return the whole string, using only pointers

Tags: c, arrays

I can release this using arrays, but i want to make it working with pointers.

```
 char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
    {
        while (*src)
        {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;
           // return dest; i want 
        }
        *dest = '\0';
        return (dest);
    }
```

Comment: Consider at what point do you have "*the whole string*" available. When do you lose it? Think.

Comment: You could look at the hundreds of other implementations of strcpy already present on SO and compare it with your code, to see what's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing your string as you increment `dest`. At the end `dest` is pointing to a location which holds `'\0'`. You can use a temporary variable for modification while `dest` is still pointing to the beginning of the allocated memory.

```
char *temp = dest;
while (*src)
{
    *temp = *src;
    temp++;
    src++;
}
*temp = '\0';
return (dest);
```

Comment: @Vladimir Try to understand [the following Program](https://ideone.com/XKyLif). Replace `dest[i] = '\0';` with `tmp[i] = '\0';` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the main C principles of pointer usage. 
When you are using dest++; you have move the pointer to next byte.
In case you have return latest dest value - you will get pointer to end of your string instead first. 
Another one - you don't need to return pointer, all pointer operations changing data into base string used like dest parameter in your example. 
So when you will finish the function you can get pointer used as dest parameter in parent function and will see your changes complete.

In case you still want some construction of function with return pointer do next:

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
    {
        char * retValue = dest;
        while (*src)
        {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;
           // return dest; i want 
        }
        *dest = '\0';
        return (retValue);
    }
```

Than you can get the pointer to first byte in the string as your return value.

Answer (score 0):

As well answered by others concerning returning the original `dest` as below,

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src) {
  char *original_dest = dest; // add
  while (*src) {
    *dest++ = *src++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  // return dest; 
  return original_dest; 
}
```

It is interesting to think about the impact of overlapping strings.  The below will cause `ft_strcpy()` to loop on and on until code accesses outside `buf[]` leading to *undefined behavior* rather than a hoped for `"hehello"`.  The `while (*src) {` loop, in this case, over wrote the *null character*.

```
char buf[10] = "hello";
ft_strcpy(buf + 2, buf);
```

Such calls as above are pathological, yet allowed.

The standard `strcpy()` disallows this type of call with `restrict`.  Simplistically, this means `s1,s2` shall not overlap.

```
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

---

How could code be written to handle overlapping strings?

Determine the length *before* copying.
Copy with `memmove()` which handles overlapping buffers.

```
char *ft_strcpy2(char *dest, const char *src) {
  size_t sz = strlen(src) + 1;
  memmove(dest, src, sz);
  return dest; 
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[10] = "hello";
  puts(ft_strcpy2(buf + 2, buf));
  puts(buf);
}
```

Output

```
hello
hehello
```